# OpenCV Draw Contours in JAVA (Android)

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm trying to draw the contour of an image in JAVA (Android) but it doesn't seem to do anything (the function doesn't draw anything) Here's the code:

```
  public Mat contours(Mat mat)
    {
        ArrayList<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

        Mat balele = new Mat();
        mat.convertTo(balele, CvType.CV_32SC1);
        // find contours:
        Imgproc.findContours(balele, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_FLOODFILL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);


        Mat source = new Mat(balele.size(), balele.type());
        for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++)
        {
            Imgproc.drawContours(source, contours, contourIdx, new Scalar(0,0,255), -1);
        }

        return source;
    }
```

The mat image is in binary format already when we pass it to the method.

Do you detect any error ?

UPDATE:
i updated the code, it looks like this:

public Mat contours(Mat mat)
{

```
ArrayList<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

// find contours:
Imgproc.findContours(mat, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
System.out.println(contours.size() + "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");

Mat source = new Mat();
for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++)
{
    Imgproc.drawContours(source, contours, contourIdx, new Scalar(0,0,255), -1);
}

return source;
```

}

Results:
[image: ORIGINAL PICTURE]

[image: FINAL PICTURE]

Im still not getting all of the contour and im getting a light white color. Any idea of a correction ?

Comment: Can you print `contours.size()`?

Comment: yeah already did, for the image im testing the result is: 5850

Comment: Ok. And what does the function return? A black matrix?

Comment: i editted the original post, can you check it ?

Comment: I have the same issue right now. The drawContours() seem only able to draw in black colour no matter what colour you set. Is it a bug of OpenCV?

Answer (score 0):

The `Imgproc.findContours` internally alters the input `Mat` which creates an artifact as shown above, You may pass the `Mat` as cloned object so that the changes are not reflected on the input `Mat`. I am not sure if there is some better solution present, because cloning `Mat` definitely has a bit of time and space over head (not too much). So you may use:

```
Imgproc.findContours(mat.clone(), contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Comment: Oh My bad then, but OP hasn't mentioned the version I guess ? @Miki

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. This is really a bug in the OpenCV library. The following code is exactly how OpenCV implement drawContours() in java. It always uses the four values scale which contains R, G, B and Alpha.

```
public static void drawContours(Mat image, List<MatOfPoint> contours, int contourIdx, Scalar color, int thickness, int lineType, Mat hierarchy, int maxLevel, Point offset) {
    List<Mat> contours_tmplm = new ArrayList<Mat>((contours != null) ? contours.size() : 0);
    Mat contours_mat = Converters.vector_vector_Point_to_Mat(contours, contours_tmplm);
    drawContours_0(image.nativeObj, contours_mat.nativeObj, contourIdx, color.val[0], color.val[1], color.val[2], color.val[3], thickness, lineType, hierarchy.nativeObj, maxLevel, offset.x, offset.y);
}
```

Now, let's think about what is the default value of alpha. Zero, Right? That's why you always draw in black. The solution is to use four values scalar such as new Scalar(0, 0, 255, 1)